# When using loopback, command prompt is garbled

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-prompt, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a question about loopback. Node js.

I am currently having the error on the command prompt, which it prints out "??????" on the screen only when I am using loopback. There was no problem when I was just using node js.

Initially I thought this is the problem related to "code page".  My active code page is 437, but this should print with no problems. I tried other code pages, but results were similar.

Any ideas or suggestions help me. Thank you.

This is how my command prompt looks like:

[image: This is how my command prompt looks like]

Comment: Share your nodejs  code

Comment: Have you tried to change your directory? Your system's name includes non-ascii characters. (C:\Users\?\...)

Comment: Ah yeah, exactly. I have Japanese character's directory. Probably loopback also tries to use Japanese characters in command prompt automatically. That's why there are "????". Do you know the solution for this?

Comment: I moved to other directories that are not Japanese characters, and tested to see if loopback displays English, but there were "????" again, so they displayed Japanese again. Probably, I have to change setting to display Japanese on command prompt.

Comment: P.S. I tried to use code page 65001, but now when I type "slc loopback", the command prompt doesn't show anything.

Comment: When I use other fonts like Consolas with code page 65001, slc loopback works but shows this "□□□ ". Then, if I change to Raster font (default) on the same screen after that, it showed Japanese character from "□□□ ", but I can't use loopback with Raster font, so I have to use Consolas to use loopback, and decoded them by changing to Raster font, and change to Consolas again to use loopback....